# Using .htaccess, how to redirct all calls for javascript files from js folder to js/min?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've created a minifyed versions of all my javaScript files, and placed them in js/min folder.

In my HTML/PHP code, I'm calling the original files located in the js folder, what are the right directives should i use in my .htaccess file to redirect all the calls to pull from the js folder to the js/min instead?

/ js

/   min/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^js/([\w.-]+)$ /js/min/$1 [L]
```

That allows for your js filenames to contain word characters (a-z, 0-9, _), dots and the `-` character.